# Laravel Row duplication inserted, with updateOrCreate method with Race-Condition

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, duplicates, race-condition

i have function in my controller that create a forecast :

```php
    public function updateOrCreate(Request $request, $subdomain, $uuid)
    {
        $fixture = Fixture::where('uuid',$uuid)->firstOrFail();
        request()->validate([
            'local_team_score' => 'integer|min:0',
            'visitor_team_score' => 'integer|min:0',
            'winner_team_id' => 'integer|nullable'
        ]);

        if ($fixture->status !== "PENDING"){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "You can not add or modify a forecast if the fixture is not pending"
            ], 403);
        }

        $winner_team = null;
        // local team win
        if ($request->local_team_score > $request->visitor_team_score) {
            $winner_team = $fixture->localTeam;
        }elseif ($request->local_team_score < $request->visitor_team_score){ //visitor win
            $winner_team = $fixture->visitorTeam;
        }else{ // draw
            $winner_team = FixtureTeam::where('team_id',$request->winner_team_id)->first();
        }

        $user = auth('api')->user();
        $platform = Platform::first();

        $forecast = Forecast::updateOrCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'fixture_id' => $fixture->id,
            'platform_id' => $platform->id
        ],[
           'local_team_score' => $request->local_team_score,
           'visitor_team_score' => $request->visitor_team_score,
           'winner_team_id' => is_null($winner_team) ? null : $winner_team->team_id
        ]);

        $forecast->load('winnerTeam');
        return new ForecastResource($forecast);
    }
```

As you can see i use updateOrCreate methods to add or update a forecast.

The problem is when 2 requests from the same user run at the same time (and no forecast is already created) 2 row are inserted.

Do you have a solution ?
I See that the problem is not new but i could not find a solution https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` does 2 steps:

1. tries to fetch the record
2. depending on the outcome  does an update or a create.
   This operation is not atomic, meaning that between step 1 and 2 another process could create the record and you would end up with duplicates (your situation).

To solve your problem you need following:

1. determine what columns would give the uniqueness of the record and add an unique index (probably compound between user_id, fixture_id, platform_id)
2. you need to let database handle the upsert (`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL, `ON CONFLICT (...) DO UPDATE SET` in Postgres, etc). This can be achieved in Laravel by using the `upsert(array $values, $uniqueBy, $update = null)` instead of `updateOrCreate`.

Comment: Might be worth noting `upsert` is only available on Laravel 8 and above